# validate coice of more than 2 radio buttons in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get some js to work in checking if one of 3 radio buttons is selected in my html form, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Currently, I'm using

```html
<label for="ctype"> Select Card Type:</label>
        <br>
        <label for="visa">Visa</label>
        <input type="radio" name="ctype" id="visa" value="visa" ></input><br>
        <label for="mastercard">Master Card</label>
        <input type="radio" name="ctype" id="mastercard" value="mastercard"></input><br>
        <label for="amex">American Express</label>
        <input type="radio" name="ctype" id="amex" value="amex"></input>
```

```js
 if (document.forms[0].visa.checked == true){
 }
 else if (document.forms[0].mastercard.checked == true){
 }
 else if (document.forms[0].amex.checked == true){
 }
 else {
  alert("Please select a credit card type.");
  return false;
 }
```

I've also tried running it with document.getElementById(visa/mastercard/amex).checked but had no luck there either.

Unfortunately, I cannot just use the html required as it has to be a js validation.

Comment: Do you have a `<form>` tag wrapping your `input`s in HTML? The `document.forms` array would be empty w/o it. Could you please show also where do you call your validation code?

Comment: hey Viktor, I do have it in a form tag, I just pulled the necessary parts directly from the form and the external js page I'm using to show my 3 buttons and how I was attempting to validate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript comparison operator is `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: That was the fastest answer I ever expected, and it fixed it perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. :) If it worked, could you accept this answer.

Comment: Will do as soon as it lets me, it's saying I have to wait another 9 minutes

Comment: @ifwa, I'm surprised the answer of @MursaleenAhmad has helped you. The difference between `===` and `==` is just that the latter does type conversion while the first one means strict equal, i.e. `5 === '5'` is `false` while `5 == '5'` is true. I've made a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/5obod1jn/) and it shows no difference for this particular case. Both versions work though.

Comment: Can you explain, why strict comparison works here but simple comparison doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the selected ctype item of a form with id myForm:

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()
```

Here's an example:

```
$('#myForm input').on('change', function() {
   alert($('input[name=ctype]:checked', '#myForm').val()); 
});
```

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="radio" name="ctype" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="ctype" value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="ctype" value="3" /> 3 <br />
</form>
```

Comment: This example requires jQuery, and it's not clarified is he uses it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//    alert(document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').outerHTML);
if (document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked')==undefined){
  alert("Please select a credit card type.");
//      return false;
 }
```

```html
<label for="ctype"> Select Card Type:</label>
        <br>
        <label for="visa">Visa</label>
        <input type="radio" name="ctype" id="visa" value="visa" checked="true" ></input><br>
        <label for="mastercard">Master Card</label>
        <input type="radio" name="ctype" id="mastercard" value="mastercard"></input><br>
        <label for="amex">American Express</label>
        <input type="radio" name="ctype" id="amex" value="amex"></input>
```